# Mostrar un modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy realizando mi pagina web, y en ella tengo un boton "DONAR" en donde el usuario hace una donación y lo que busco es que aparezca un mensaje tipo pop up, o modal, que sea de agradecimiento.
Estoy recién iniciado en JS y estoy aprendiendo con ayuda de algunas guias de internet, pero en todas me sucede lo mismo y es que no me funciona, el modal ni siquiera se muestra cuando presiono el boton, solo se hace un refresh de pagina.
Cabe destacar que en mi HTML SÍ esta linkeado la hoja de JS.

```js
if(document.getElementById("boton_donar")){
   var modal = document.getElementById("myModal-donar");
   var boton = document.getElementById("boton_donar");
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
   var body = document.getElementById("body_ayudanos");

   boton.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      body.style.position = "static";
      body.style.height = "100%";
      body.style.overflow = "hidden";
   }

   span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      body.style.position = "inherit";
      body.style.height = "auto";
      body.style.overflow = "visible";
   }

   window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
         modal.style.display = "none";
         body.style.position = "inherit";
         body.style.height = "auto";
         body.style.overflow = "visible";
      }
   }
}
```

```css
#boton_donar{
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #8E44AD;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#boton_donar:hover{
    background-color: mediumpurple; /* Green */
    color: black;
}

.modalContainer-donar {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /*oscurece el fondo*/
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);/*oscurece el fondo*/
}

.modalContainer-donar .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-top: 10px solid #8E44AD;
    width: 60%;
}

#gracias-donar{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.modalContainer-donar .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modalContainer-donar .close:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal-donar"class="modalContainer-donar">
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">×</span>
<h2 id="gracias-donar">¡Muchas Gracias!</h2>
<p>Con su contribución ayuda a Naturalia a continuar con su trabajo por un mundo mejor</p> 
</div>
</div>

<button id="boton_donar" >DONAR</button>
```

Comment: Probe tu codigo y si sale el modal. Lo que podria ser es que js guarda cache te recomendaria limpiar tu cache de la pagina a lo mejor es eso

Comment: Las preguntas en stack overflow deben ser AUTOCONTENIDAS. Es decir, todo el código relevante debe estar en la pregunta, NO en un enlace externo. Mañana borras el codepen y la pregunta pierde sentido. Por favor, incluye el código en tu pregunta. StackOverflow proporciona snippets (`botón <>`) que prestan la misma funcionalidad de codepen y te permiten reproducir código html, css y js desde acá. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/537451/edit) colocando el código.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez perdona no sabía eso, ahi lo modifique. Espero que ahora esté a tu gusto :) Saludos

Comment: @igna1225 no es mero gusto mío, es así como funciona el sitio. Ahora ... ¿Cuál es el problema? Cómo puedes apreciar desde tu propia pregunta. El modal se muestra.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez justamente mi pregunta dice que el modal no se muestra al presionar el boton, y es raro porque en el link que cree para mostrar el codigo con el codepen si lo mostraba. Uso WebStorm como entorno.

Comment: Lo raro es que tanto acá como en codepen se muestren y en tu código no. Pregunta, ¿En tu código original tienes algún elemento con id `body_ayudanos`? No lo veo. Probablemente ese sea el error en donde sea que lo estás ejecutando. Que no encuentra elemento con ese id, y detiene la ejecución. Es lo único raro que veo. ¿Tendrás linkeado correctamente tu archivo de javascript? ¿Aparece algún error en la consola?

Comment: Asegúrate de tener tu javascript al final de la página, de lo contrario no va a funcionar. Hay alternativas como `defer` o usar el evento `onload`, pero la más directa es ponerlo al final del body.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez el id "body_ayudanos" esta en la etiqueta BODY de todo el html. Yo lo que puse aca es solo un fragmento de mi html ya que todo el resto es irrelevante. No me aparecen errores de consola y acabo de intentar lo de ponerlo al final al linkeo de JS y tampoco... :c

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez de ultima podrias decirme como harias tu el js con el html que publique para que me muestre un modal al presionar el boton Donar? Aver si funciona..

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque desde js estas definiendo el position static por lo que no se pondra sobre los demas elementos, aqui en tu snippet se muestra bien porque no hay elementos que lo muevan.... en tu css ya tienes indicado el position en fixed por lo que solo debes eliminar la linea en donde lo defines en js....

como recomendacion para codigo mas limpio, usa una clase css para cuando el modal este activo y hay aplicas los estilos para mostrarlo y desde el js solo aplicas esa clase al elemento

ejemplo:

```
.mostrar-modal { display: block; }
```

y desde el js

```
modal.classList.add('mostrar-modal');
```

(`.classList.remove('mostrar-modal');` para ocultarlo de nuevo).